# Sort of alias in CentOS?

Tags: centos

I have a network of 37 computers, all running CentOS, in spanish.
Some of them run CentOS 5, while others run CentOS 6.

Every day, via cron, I send a file to every one of the 37 computers, to the path "/root/Desktop".

The problem I have, is that CentOS 6 has changed their naming, now calling /root/Desktop "/root/Escritorio" (Escritorio means Desktop in spanish). Because of this change, my files are no longer being put in the user's Desktop when the computer is running CentOS 6.

What can I do at the specific computers that run centos 6 so that when I send a file to /root/Desktop it knows to place it in /root/Escritorio instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem you could solve using symbolic links.

For example, you could make a symbolic link in the stead of a "Desktop" directory. This can be accomplished witha single command, given that the /root/Desktop directory does not exist (and that /root/Escritorio does exist).

`# ln -s /root/Escritorio /root/Desktop`

This will direct everything placed in /root/Desktop to /root/Escritorio.

Answer (score 0):

put this line in .bashrc :`Alias DESKTOP='/root/Escritorio'`

then just sent whatever you wanna sent to $DESKTOP

Comment: cron is not an interactive shell, so it dosen't read .bashrc